# Build a dataframe based on one repetetive row

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a row and I want to build a dataframe based on this row. For example, I have a row with 5 value. I want to build a df with 4 rows and 5 column. here is the
desired output for me:

```
df = pd.DataFrame()
df['a']=[1]
df['b']=[2]
df['c']=[3]
df['d']=[1]
df['e']=[2]
```

Output:

```
      a     b     c     d     e
0     1     2     3     1     2
1     1     2     3     1     2
2     1     2     3     1     2
3     1     2     3     1     2
```

Can you help me with it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can `repeat` the index:

```
out = (df.loc[df.index.repeat(4)]
         .reset_index(drop=True)
      )
```

Output:

```
   a  b  c  d  e
0  1  2  3  1  2
1  1  2  3  1  2
2  1  2  3  1  2
3  1  2  3  1  2
```

Used input:

```
d = {'a': [1], 'b': [2], 'c': [3], 'd': [1], 'e': [2]}
df = pd.DataFrame(d)
```

#### rows and columns

Using `repeat`:

```
df.loc[df.index.repeat(4), df.columns.repeat(2)].reset_index(drop=True)
```

Output:

```
   a  a  b  b  c  c  d  d  e  e
0  1  1  2  2  3  3  1  1  2  2
1  1  1  2  2  3  3  1  1  2  2
2  1  1  2  2  3  3  1  1  2  2
3  1  1  2  2  3  3  1  1  2  2
```

Using `numpy.tile` for a different order:

```
import numpy as np
df.loc[df.index.repeat(4), np.tile(df.columns, 2)].reset_index(drop=True)
```

Output:

```
   a  b  c  d  e  a  b  c  d  e
0  1  2  3  1  2  1  2  3  1  2
1  1  2  3  1  2  1  2  3  1  2
2  1  2  3  1  2  1  2  3  1  2
3  1  2  3  1  2  1  2  3  1  2
```

Comment: Thanks. However, with this way, it build the first column and then build the second column same as first. like (1,1,2,2,3,3,1,1,2,2). I want (1,2,3,1,2,1,2,3,1,2) for each row.

Answer (score 3):

Use `pandas.concat`

```
n = 4 
res = pd.concat([df]*n, ignore_index=True)
```

Example:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2, 3, 1, 2]], columns=list('abcde'))
>>> df

   a  b  c  d  e
0  1  2  3  1  2

>>> pd.concat([df]*4, ignore_index=True)

   a  b  c  d  e
0  1  2  3  1  2
1  1  2  3  1  2
2  1  2  3  1  2
3  1  2  3  1  2
```

Comment: `concat` is quite slow for this kind of task. For example if you repeat 100k times it takes 3 seconds with `concat` but only 20 milliseconds with `index.repeat` ;)

Comment: @mozway I doubt OP wants to repeat 100k times that row, so performance is relative and not all :p  But I agree that using a pure index-based approach is clever and useful here +1

Comment: Sure, I was just mentioning this for completeness, it's always good to know IMO ;)

Comment: @mozway I appreciate your note, but I am aware that using the pure index-based approach will always be much faster than using `pd.concat`. I just didn't occur to me, because it is the force of habit to use `pd.concat` for the sake of simplicity and readability ;)